# How to analyze all the data in a directory

Tags: export, import, dataset

I am trying to import, analyze, and save all the .txt files in a specific directory. I can do this with a single .txt file using the following code:

```
data= Import["D:Experiments\\raw-data.txt", "Table"];
range = Select[data, 400 < #[[1]] < 550 &];
smooth = Interpolation[range, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
ex = Table[{x,smooth[x]}, {x, 400, 550, 0.050}];
Export["D:Experiments\\raw-data-out.txt", ex, "Table"];
```

Could you help me how to perform this process for all the .txt files in my specific directory at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
SetDirectory["D:Experiments\\"];
names = FileNames["*.txt"];
Do[
    data = Import[name, "Table"];
    range = Select[data, 400 < #[[1]] < 550 &];
    smooth = Interpolation[range, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
    ex = Table[{x,smooth[x]}, {x, 400, 550, 0.050}];
    Export[FileBaseName[name]<>"-out.txt", ex, "Table"];,
{name, names}]
```